# ошибка при проигрывании звука (playsound,python, 263 ошибка)

Tags: python, синтезатор-речи, playsound

я использую playsound чтобы проиграть звук который мне сгенерировала библиотека gtts.
Но когда я использую её много раз всё улетает в ошибку (не только с этой, но и другими модулями для проигрывания звуков  библиотеками), код приложу ниже, ошибка

> ***playsound.PlaysoundException:
> Error 263 for command:
> open test.mp3
> Указанное устройство не открыто или не опознается интерфейсом MCI.***

```
import gtts
import  playsound
import os
def text(text):
    if os.path.exists("test.mp3") == True:
        os.remove("test.mp3")
    tts = gtts.gTTS(str(text),lang="ru")
    tts.save("test.mp3")
    playsound.playsound("test.mp3")
while 1:
    text(str(input("текст ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет переустановка модуля на конкретную версию 1.2.2:

```
pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

Comment: Как вы определили, что именно эта версия нужна?

Comment: Однажды столкнулся сам, после погуглил, теперь просто знаю. Последняя версия 1.3.0 нестабильна и если зайти в оф репозиторий на github и перейти во вкладку issues, можно будет увидеть много репортов ошибки 263, там и рекомендуют откатиться до версии 1.2.2.

Comment: Ок, лучше эти детали указать в вопросе, чтобы не было впечатления, что это какая-то взятая из головы цифра.